Radon measure on $\sigma$-compact space, $\mu(U) = \int_{U} f d\mu$ for open sets $U$. Prove $f =1$ a.e.
Problem: Let $X$ be a $\sigma$-compact LCH.Let $\mu$ be a Radon measure on $X$. Let $f\geq 0$
be a measurable function. Prove that if for any open subset $U$ such that $\mu(U) =\int_{U} fd\mu$. Then $f=1$ $\mu$-a.e.
My effort: Since $X$ is $\sigma$-compact, then $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite (and regular). Let $E := \{x: f(x) > 1\}$ (which is measurable as $f$ is measurable). Let $U \supseteq E$ be an open set, we have $\mu(U) = \int_{E} f d\mu + \int_{U\setminus E} f d\mu  > \mu(E) + \int_{U\setminus E} f d\mu$. And we may use outer regularity to make $\int_{U\setminus E} f d\mu$ fairly small so that we are done. (Also, we need to first decompose $E$ into countable union of finite measure sets and do this operations). I don't know how to proceed then...Can anyone help me with this?

Fix $\epsilon>0$, pick any compact $K$. Let $E := \{x: f(x) > 1\}$ and $E_K:=E\cap K$. We can find open $U\supset E_K$ s.t. $\mu(U\setminus E_K)<\epsilon$. We have $\mu(U\setminus E_K)+\mu(E_K)=\mu(U)=\int_{U} fd\mu \geq \int_{E_K} fd\mu$. Hence, $\epsilon> \mu(U\setminus E_K) \geq \int_{E_K} fd\mu-\mu(E_K)=\int_{E_K} f-1d\mu$. Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, and $f>1$ on $E_K$, we must have $\int_{E_K} f-1d\mu=0$. From which it follows that $\mu(E_K)=0$; $\sigma$-compactness of $X$ now implies that $\mu(E)=0$. Next, let $F := \{x: f(x) < 1\}$, $F_K:=F\cap K$, and $V\supset F_K$ be open s.t. $\mu(V\setminus F_K)<\epsilon$. Since $f\leq 1$ a.e., $\mu(V\setminus F_K)\geq \int_{V\setminus F_K} fd\mu$, hence $\epsilon> \int_{V\setminus F_K} fd\mu =\mu(V)-\int_{F_K} fd\mu \geq \mu(F_K)-\int_{F_K} fd\mu=\int_{F_K}1-fd\mu$. Similarily as before, this forces $\mu(F_K)=0$, and thus $\mu(F)=0$.
